# Switch Statement: Execute Code Once

Tags: java, switch-statement

If I have a switch statement testing the value of integer `i`, how can I execute the same code once?

For example:

```
switch(i) {
case 0:
    if(j == 2) {
        booleanA = true;
        booleanB = false;
case 1:
    if(j == 4) {
        booleanA = true;
        booleanB = false;
}
```

With 5 different cases, instead of me having to type out

```
booleanA = true;
booleanB = false;
```

five times, is there a way to say if one of the `if` statements is true, use this block of code? Is that possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe making a method?

Comment: First of all add `break;` after each `case`, second, I don't understand your question..

Comment: make a class variable as the bolean variable . and have methods to set or reset

Comment: @Christian Yeah, I'll do that. It just doesn't really seem necessary for two lines of code. But thanks anyway!

Comment: I think OP is asking how to ignore writing  booleanA = true;
        booleanB = false;  again and again.

Comment: @AchintyaJha yes, that is what I'm asking.

Comment: Are there different values of **i** and you want to check for all of them with the same switch block ?

Comment: It is certainly possible to refactor your code, but you have not shown enough code for us to know how it *should* be refactored. Maybe you should have a method that takes `i` and `j` and returns whether these assignments should be run? Maybe you should keep the switch, and use a tracker Boolean to record whether these assignments should be run? Maybe you should dispense with the switch, and just use a multi-pronged `if`? Maybe you should examine why you have so many cases where you assign the same pair of Boolean variables in the same way?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without a switch statement...

```
    int[] requiredJ = {2,4};
    if (j == requiredJ[i]) { 
        booleanA = true;
        booleanB = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I can not understand logic behind your code, but may be this can be done ( Like switch hit in cricket !!! :p).

Assign the values to your booleans, and revert in default case.

```
booleanA = true;
booleanB = false;

// more code blocks

switch(i) {
case 0:
    // Process
    break;
case 1:
    // Process
    break;
default :
    booleanA = false;
    booleanB = true;
}
```